# How to set font size of a GTK label with gi-gtk-declarative?

Tags: haskell, gtk, font-size, gobject-introspection

I want larger text but am not sure how. (I found `Label` has an `attributes` attribute of type `PangoAttrList` but can't figure out how to construct the latter (if indeed that is how one sets the font size) in a context where it can be set on the `Label` widget.)

A minimal example follows:

```
#!/usr/bin/env cabal
{- cabal:
build-depends:
  , base ^>= 4.13
  , gi-gtk
  , gi-gtk-declarative
  , gi-gtk-declarative-app-simple
ghc-options:
  -Wall
  -threaded
-}

{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedLabels #-}
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedLists #-}
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}

import Data.Void (absurd)

import qualified GI.Gtk as Gtk hiding ((:=), on)
import qualified GI.Gtk.Declarative as Gtk
import qualified GI.Gtk.Declarative.App.Simple as Gtk

main :: IO ()
main = () <$ Gtk.run Gtk.App
  { Gtk.view = \ () ->
        Gtk.bin Gtk.Window [#title Gtk.:= "example"] $
        Gtk.widget Gtk.Label [#label Gtk.:= "foobar" {- What should be here? -}]
  , Gtk.update = \ () -> absurd
  , Gtk.inputs = []
  , Gtk.initialState = ()
  }
```